# mysql max strict mode

Tags: mysql, max, mysql-error-1093

I have the following query:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE node_id = ".$id." 
AND date < (
            SELECT
                (MAX(date)- INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
            from table1  
            WHERE node_id = ".$id."
)
```

However due to mysql strict mode being enabled i get the error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause
```

After investigation online i attempted to recreate the query as below:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM table1 as tb1 
INNER JOIN table1 as tb2 
    on tb1.id = tb2.id 
HAVING tb1.date < MAX(tb2.date)-INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND tb1.node_id = 1;
```

However the result set is returning empty.

I have changed `max(tb2.date)` to a manually entered date which gave me the results I was expecting.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: try to use alice name for table

Comment: who the !"£% is alice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try this?

## Using JOIN

**Data**

```
mysql> select * from test;
+---------+------------+
| node_id | dt         |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2011-03-01 |
|       1 | 2011-02-01 |
|       1 | 2011-01-01 |
+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**SELECT**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(dt) AS max_dt
  FROM test
  WHERE node_id = 1
) x INNER JOIN test ON test.node_id = 1 AND test.dt < x.max_dt;
+------------+---------+------------+
| max_dt     | node_id | dt         |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 2011-03-01 |       1 | 2011-01-01 |
| 2011-03-01 |       1 | 2011-02-01 |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

**DELETE**

```
DELETE test
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(dt) AS max_dt
  FROM test
  WHERE node_id = 1
) x INNER JOIN test ON test.node_id = 1 AND test.dt < x.max_dt;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

**Check**

```
mysql> select * from test;
+---------+------------+
| node_id | dt         |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2011-03-01 |
+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Using Variable

In your case, you are trying to delete just one node_id. That makes simple query.

```
SELECT @max_dt := MAX(dt)
FROM test  
WHERE node_id = 1;
+--------------------+
| @max_dt := MAX(dt) |
+--------------------+
| 2011-03-01         |
+--------------------+


DELETE FROM test 
WHERE node_id = 1
AND dt < @max_dt;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

## BTW

You asked 17 questions but hadn't accepted any answer. Are there no useful answers?